# How to decode special character in Request.QueryString?

Tags: asp.net

I am passing '© Alt+ 0169' in my serach fields in query string.

When i am getting QueryString in page like Request.QueryString("SearchVal") then value will be : '© Alt 0169' .

It reomove '+'.

Could u tell me how can i get it..

Thanks 
Pankaj Pareek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` method.

```
string encode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("© Alt+ 0169");
Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx?searchVal=" + encode);
```

Comment: I am using javascript like this:-window.location.href='Test.aspx?SearchVal=' + strSearch and this strSearch = © Alt+ 0169 If i am using Server.UrlEncode then string changed.

Comment: Please check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript